# Rails form and HTML/CSS template marriage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I've purchased a HTML/CSS template to use for a Rails app.  I have the Rails app playing well with the template by placing the template code as a layout, then using <%= yield %> to place the rails content into the template.  Everything works fine, including the CSS stylings.

One wrinkle....

I can't seem to get the Log-in screen to work.  The trouble seems to be in replacing the way the template processes a form (HTML and CSS issue) and the way Rails wants a form to be passed.

Here's the template form area:

```
<body id="login">
    <header>
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="login.html">whitelabel</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section id="content">
    <form action="submit.php" id="loginform">
        <fieldset>
            <section><label for="username">Username</label>
                <div><input type="text" id="username" name="username" autofocus></div>
            </section>
            <section><label for="password">Password <a href="#">lost password?</a></label>
                <div><input type="password" id="password" name="password"></div>
                <div><input type="checkbox" id="remember" name="remember"><label for="remember" class="checkbox">remember me</label></div>
            </section>
            <section>
                <div><button class="fr submit">Login</button></div>
            </section>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </section>
    <footer>Copyright by revaxarts.com 2011</footer>
```

And here's the standard Rails login form code (using Devise views)

```
    <h2>Sign in</h2>

    <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
     <p><%= f.label :emailer %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

    <p><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

    <p><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></p>
    <% end %>

    <%= render :partial => "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to introduce the CSS instructions into the existing Rails form_for parts.  I've tried lots of different combos, but nothing works.

Lastly, except for the CSS styling, the form will submit and let me into the app, so I know the back-end Devise wiring is working.  It just wont take the CSS styling.

Also, I can cut-paste the entire code from the template log-in screen, and the log-in fields load with the correct CSS styling, so I know that the  part points to the right CSS and JS files and that they are present and working.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to add the CSS id and class parameters to the view:

```
<%= form_for ..., :class => 'someclass', :id => 'someid' %>
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html